# ログインフォームの自動補完を選択後の自動遷移について

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

ログインフォームの自動補完を選択すると自動遷移する現象があるのですが
クライアントから自動補完は残していいのですが自動遷移を止めて欲しいと希望があるのですが
どのようにHTML,CSS、JSなどで対策できますか？

現在は、Wordpressにて利用しているのでいいアイディアや参考になるサイトなどがあればご教授いただければ幸いです。

OSレベルの問題かと思っているのですが、、、

Comment: そもそも、その「自動補完」や「自動で遷移」は何がトリガーになっているのかを特定出来ていますか？(ブラウザ自体の機能、ブラウザの拡張機能、OS 上のアプリ等…)

Comment: 回答をありがとうございます。補足追加になりますが
ブラウザ自体とOS自体の補完になります。拡張機能ではないのは確かですし、ソースコードでは制御していません。なので、技術的にわからなくて今回の質問したという形になります。